# Null pointer Exception when write a image in opencv

Tags: java, opencv

I try to crop the image in opencv 2.4.10 java.

My code

my java class name is FaceDetector

```
Mat srcImg= Highgui.imread("china.jpg"),dstImg=null;
Rect rect = new Rect( x, y, width, height ); 
        srcImg(rect).copyTo(dstImg); 
        Highgui.imwrite("screen.jpg", dstImg);
```

The error is

srcImg(rect) is undefined for the type FaceDetector

Null pointer Exception at //srcImg(rect).copyTo(dstImg);

help to solve this error

Thanks

Comment: Please check that your image name is case sensitive including extension and file is placed at the correct path

Comment: I checked it everything is correct still the error is occured. please consider the first one  srcImg(rect) error. Help to solve this one first...  Thanks for your reply@ Aman

Comment: Try to pass the absolute path like. File file = new File("china.jpg"); Mat m = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: The null pointer exception occured in dstImg not in "china.jpg"  Thanks@ Aman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Long time I got the solution.

```
 Mat crop=new Mat();

      crop=srcImg.submat(x,width,y,height);
      Highgui.imwrite("screen3.jpg", crop);
```

Now my detected face was cropped clearly.

Answer (score 0):

1) img(Rect) is valid in c++, but in java you need:

```
img.submat(Rect)
```

1a) before doing so, see, if the desired Rect completely fits into your img, 
    clip it to the img bounds else (yes, that happens, e.g. the FaceDetection will eventually return out-of-bounds Rects !):

```
Rect r;
int ox = (r.x + r.width) - img.cols() - 1;
if ( ox > 0 ) r.width -= ox;

int oy = (r.y + r.height) - img.rows() - 1;
if ( oy > 0 ) r.width -= ox;
```

2) copyTo() needs a valid target (an image large enough). since you want to assign it to a new image anyway , use

```
Mat dstImg = srcImg.submat(Rect).clone();
```

3) whenever you load resources, check the outcome !

```
Mat srcImg= Highgui.imread("china.jpg");
if ( srcImg.empty() )
    // baah
```

Comment: I try your guidelines.  My rect values is(x:=49y:=64width:=186height=201)    The error occured at run time in                            Mat dstImg = srcImg.submat(rect).clone();    error is   at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_submat(Native Method)
 at org.opencv.core.Mat.submat(Mat.java:2325)  Thanks @berak

Comment: oh,  saturday's sloppiness, my bad. i guess, you will have to check, if the Rect actually fits into your image (it's a different error now, right ?)

Comment: Thank you. The rect values are not fit into my image. now i correct it. Thanks a lot @berak